# Need a MySQL query to delete duplicate comments

Tags: comments, mysql, disqus

My wordpress site was recently hacked so I had to reinstall everything. Wordpress resinstalled, database backups imported, everything fine and dandy. Then I installed the Disqus plugin and synced (Disqus was previously used before the site was hacked). Big no-no apparantly. Now I have a duplicate of every single comment on my site! Even worse, the duplicate comments have been synced BACK to Disqus!

So, I know this is a simple query in PHPMyAdmin but I don't know it! Please help!

Comment: This belongs in __StackOverflow.com__ in my opinion since it's just an SQL question. :)

Answer (score 2):

D'oh, I just posted this as someone migrated it to SO...! Fortunately I have an account here too :)

**FOR THE LOVE OF GOD BACK YOUR DATABASE UP FIRST**

I haven't tried this query as I don't have a spare database to play around with.

This should help you though:

```
table1 = your table name
field_name = a field in your database.

DELETE FROM table1
USING table1, table1 as vtable
WHERE (NOT table1.ID=vtable.ID)
AND (table1.field_name=vtable.field_name)
```

As it's WordPress comments, presuming a prefix of `wp`, I'd probably recommend....

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments
USING wp_comments, wp_comments as vtable
WHERE (NOT wp_comments.ID=vtable.ID)
AND (wp_comments.comment_content=vtable.comment_content)
```

Hope that helps. Please read the note in bold before even contemplating running this query.

Comment: Just a quick question... How does this query determine whether or not a post is a duplicate?

Comment: Basically, it replicates your table. It then checks every comment side by side. If the comments have the same ID, it won't delete them. If the comments however have a different ID but the same `comment_content` (i.e. a duplicate), then it will delete the duplicate.